# Как сделать Material Design Календарь на Android (см. скриншот)?

Tags: android, интерфейс, material-design, toolbar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой `Material Design` Календарь под *Android*?  Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки? Интересует именно дизайнерское решение.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё, что на скриншоте сделано с помощью библиотеки [Android Design Support Library](http://www.fandroid.info/android-design-support-library-podderzhka-komponentov-material-design-v-prilozheniyah-s-android-2-1-do-android-5-s-primerami/) от гугла.

В данном случае эта разметка содержит:

1. `CoordinatorLayout`, а в нём
2. `AppBar`, а в нём
3. `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, а в нём
4. `Toolbar` и (наверное) `GridView` (для календаря)
5. В `CoordinatorLayout` также еще `RecyclerView` (или `ScrollView`) и `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! Спасибо!)